# maven-ear-plugin contextRoot ignored

Tags: java, maven, maven-ear-plugin

I've been using maven-ear-plugin to create ear bundle and generate application.xml with custom contextRoot (everything works fine). Now I want to create 2 ear bundles and deploy them under different context path, so I defined plugin with 2 executions. But for some reason, maven-ear-plugin ignores contextRoot property and in generated application.xml it is using artifactId instead of contextRoot in both ears (so they have same context-root "app-ui").
Here is my maven-ear-plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>app1</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>ear</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>app1</finalName>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
                        <artifactId>app-ui</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/app1-ui</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>app2</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>ear</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>app2</finalName>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
                        <artifactId>app-ui</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/app2-ui</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Add a `classifier` to one of the executions which means add `<classifier>Second</classifier>´ to one of the execution configurations and retry.

Comment: I tried to add classifier, but result is still same. It just add classifier to ear file name.

Comment: Can you put an example project or the real project somewhere so it's simpler too look at.

Comment: Of course. I put it on bitbucket, you can clone it:   git clone https://dd_repo@bitbucket.org/dd_repo/app.git   First build app-ui, then app-ear. Both app1.ear and app2.ear will be created and both will have same context-root in META-INF/application.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you generate the `application.xml` only once while you need two `application.xml`. For this you need to put also two executions of the `generate-application-xml` goal binded on the `generate-resources` phase of the maven lifecycle in order to generate the `application.xml` file two times (in two different folders preferably ^^) with two different configurations like this :

```xml
<!-- first execution for the first application.xml in folder target/app1/META-INF -->
<execution>
    <id>appxml-app1</id>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <generatedDescriptorLocation>target/app1/META-INF</generatedDescriptorLocation>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
                <artifactId>app-ui</artifactId>
                <contextRoot>/app1-ui</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<!-- first execution for the generation of the ear with the application.xml in folder target/app1 -->
<execution>
    <id>app1</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>ear</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <workDirectory>target/app1</workDirectory>
        <finalName>app1</finalName>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
                <artifactId>app-ui</artifactId>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</execution>

<!-- second execution for the second application.xml in folder target/app2/META-INF -->
<execution>
    <id>appxml-app2</id>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <generatedDescriptorLocation>target/app2/META-INF</generatedDescriptorLocation>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
                <artifactId>app-ui</artifactId>
                <contextRoot>/app2-ui</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<!-- second execution for the generation of the ear with the application.xml in folder target/app2 -->
<execution>
    <id>app2</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>ear</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <workDirectory>target/app2</workDirectory>
        <finalName>app2</finalName>
        <modules>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
                <artifactId>app-ui</artifactId>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

To improve this, you can use variables to ensure that the folders will be the same for the two executions that concerns app1, etc, this is just a draft ;)

Comment: You are absolutely right, Fabien. Thank you very much!